# How to export a Raster attribute table into a .txt using Model Builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, export

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1

I need to export a Raster attribute table into a .txt (or any other format Excel can import), using Model Builder.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can also specify .txt in the output file name if you would like the table exported as a text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [Table to Table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000027000000) tool and export to a dbf format. Excel can read dbf files.